# How to save an array of unsigned char to MySQL

Tags: mysql, qt, fingerprint

Any idea on how to save an array of `unsigned char` to a field in MySQL database ? I'm considering BLOB, but how can I convert it to `QByteArray` and convert it back to an array of `unsigned char` when I want to ? BTW, I'm trying to save fingerprint data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the codes below (copied directly from my project)

```
struct fp {
    unsigned char Template[MAX_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
    int size;
};
```

```
// unsigned char to QByteArray
QByteArray FingerPrint::charArrayToByteArray(fp fp0) {

    QByteArray ba;
    for (int i=0; i





// QByteArray to unsigned char
fp FingerPrint::byteToFp(QByteArray *ba) {

    fp fp0;

    for (int i=0; isize(); i++) {
        fp0.Template[i] = ba->at(i);
    }
    fp0.size = ba->size();

    return fp0;
}
```